# Coupling css file with html

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of html code for a button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
Passengers: <input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button onclick="myFunction2()">-</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">+</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
}
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepDown(1);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to work with a css file (style2.css) to change the appearance of this button (Color, size etc.). How do I go about this? I already created a css file, but I don't know how to make the changes.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: what is your css code?

Comment: I do not have anything written in the  css since I don't know where to start 
(e.g. what are the names of the buttons I should use in the css file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a ID or class for your button and implement it in your html-file.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="button">+</button>
```

Now you can change the style of your button in the css-file:
for example:

```
#button
{
    background-color: #09399b;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 99%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

This is just a example.

For more ideas, how you can style (for e.g. a round button) your button, you can search stackoverflow or google. It helps always a lot.

Comment: Thanks! that was quite usefull. But how do I couple the id of every button to the respective specifications in the css file?

Comment: id should start with `#`, not `.`

Comment: if you have many buttons, which you want to look the same, you can refer to the same style. The styles can be used as often as you want. `<button onclick="myFunction2()" id="button">-</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="button">+</button>`. Those 2 buttons will look now the same.

Comment: @Banzay I have edited my script. Thx

Comment: id shouldn't meet more than once in the html. if that happens, it should be class.

Comment: You can use both. ID will be handled more prioritized than class. That's the difference.

Comment: IDs are meant for single instances, while classes are meant for multiple, regardless of prioritization. https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Im starting to get it now guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open up a text editor of your choice or whatever you are currently using. Make sure to save it as the same thing it is named as in that html doc there "style2.css". Then you can write your CSS in that file and your HTML will base it's styling on whatever is located in that CSS file, that's what the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />` does. I suggest then going to [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/) and looking up CSS tutorials for basics, they have an entire tutorial you can do on CSS alone.

If you want to specifically change the button (This will change all buttons), you could write:

```
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none; /* No border */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 15px 32px; /* Changes the padding (inside space) of button */
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; 
}
```

Comment: where in the html a `class="button"` mentioned? Do you mean `button {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

open file style2.css and add

```
button {
  background-color: #000;
  border: solid 2px #222;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

etc... look book of css http://www.cssnewbie.com/top-10-html-css-books-developers/

Comment: Thank you, will check it out;)

Comment: @aeengineer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for are css selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

you can give different elements different classes or id´s or you can select all elements of one sort and many other things.

Just check the above link should be pretty simple to understand. When I started I found https://flukeout.github.io/ pretty usefull to learn how those selectors work. It´s a simple way to learn the selectors with a little game.

Comment: Thanks for the link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
Passengers: <input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction2()">-</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="myFunction()">+</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
}
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepDown(1);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### style2.css

```
#btn1{background-color:orange;height:50px}
#btn2{background-color:green;width:200px}
```